# How to use two SPSS factor scores to generate one social vulnerability index value

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, principal-component-analysis

I am trying to produce a single value representing social vulnerability based on 6 z-score normalized demographic variables for 55 geographic areas. I have successfully done a factor analysis on the 6 variable and computed the factor scores (using Bartlett) in SPSS for the 2 factors generated from my inclusion criteria (eigenvalues > 1, break in scree plot and cumulative variance over 80%). Now I need to turn these two factor scores into one useful number representing the social vulnerability of each area. Do I just sum the two factor scores? Should I z-score normalize them?

I will then be multiplying the vulnerability index with other target layers (heat stress and population density), how do I make sure the vulnerability value is on a useful scale compared with the other target layer values?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:linear-algebra]?

Comment: I would consider PCA, eigenvalues etc a part of linear algebra? Which tags would you suggest instead? I wanted eg factor analysis, spss, sas, etc but they didn't exist

Comment: Yes, it is a part of statistics. But your question is mainly about statistics. I suggest that you remove the [tag:linear-algebra] tag and replace it with [tag:eigenvalues-eigenvectors].